# Zest: export diagram to an image/pdf

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have created a network view diagram using zest framework, this uses SWT display/shell to display the UI. I want to export the UI to an image/pdf.
How to do it? Any ideas?

Comment: May be http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0489.html will help?

Comment: @yggdraa  I've not worked with Zest before. But since everything is built on SWT and JFace, you certainly have better and more sophisticated export options than just taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SWT GC.copyArea() method to copy the contents of a Control to an Image, then save the Image to file. For example, if you have a Zest GraphViewer, *viewer*, the following code will copy its contents to a PNG file named *out.png*.

```
GC gc = new GC(viewer.getControl());
Rectangle bounds = viewer.getControl().getBounds();
Image image = new Image(viewer.getControl().getDisplay(), bounds);
try {
    gc.copyArea(image, 0, 0);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
    imageLoader.data = new ImageData[] { image.getImageData() };
    imageLoader.save("c:\\out.png", SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
} finally {
    image.dispose();
    gc.dispose();
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work if the diagram is big enough, so you must scroll to the right/or bottom. Do you have any workaround to this issue?