# How to render graphical to JPG from Eclipse Zest

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-gef, zest

I have implemented the model visualisation using Eclipse Zest Toolkit. Now I want to save the visual model into JPEG image. How can I achieve this goal?

**EDITED:**
I have tried implementing the code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10735505/476917). But the captured image is cropped because there is vertical scrollbar there in my view (see the picture):
[image]

Comment: I think the answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718446/zest-export-diagram-to-an-image-pdf

Comment: Try removing the `bounds` argument from the call to the `Image` constructor. Is this allowed?

Comment: @Hassan: I dont think that's the solution. Actually, what I want is to capture the diagram (figures) inside the view (graphViewer) and not to include the scrollbar and other part of graphViewer.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code (originating from the Plug-in dependency visualization example in PDE) for this reason:

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/debugvisualisation/source/browse/hu.cubussapiens.debugvisualisation/src/hu/cubussapiens/debugvisualisation/internal/widgets/VisualisationGraphViewer.java

If I remember correctly, this handles the scrolling issue (but am not sure about that).

Comment: okay, I will try this approach later and will tell you if success or not :D